# How to clear back stack when Home button is pressed

Tags: android

I created an Home application wich as customized applications that I want to be launched.

The problem is that when I launch an application and then press HOME I want to empty all back stack, so that when I press BACK button dont return to the application.

The actual behaviour is:

**HOME >> APP >> (HOME BUTTON PRESSED) >> HOME >> (BACK BUTTON PRESSED) >> APP**

The desired behaviour is:

**HOME >> APP >> (HOME BUTTON PRESSED) >> HOME >> (BACK BUTTON PRESSED) >> (DO NOTHING!)**

Any suggestion?!

Comment: your problem is not clear.make it clear first

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: on home activity I did:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    // do nothing: avoid access to back stack from home
}
```